# In After Effects Expressions, how to reference a Null Object in other comp?

Tags: expression, after-effects

I am looking how to link a **layer position property** in one comp to a **null position property** that is in another comp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply this expression to the layer position property, replacing the names with their respective values:

`comp("NAME_OF_COMP").layer("NAME_OF_NULL_LAYER").transform.position;`

Let me know if this works!

Comment: That works. I actually figured it out and tried to post but it would not let me. Thanks soooo much for your help. Bless you friend.